# Average Closing Prices - plot simple line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Currently in my script when conditions are met it creates a bar_index.

For example Bar_Index is Day 0, I would like to average the closing price dynamically on Day0, Day 5, Day 10, Day 15 Day 20 and Day 30 and adjust the horizontal line with the price accordingly as each new data point is calculated.

If Day 0 = $10 and Day 5 = $12, the horizontal line is $11, until Day 10 when price is $15, the the horizontal line is $12.33. etc.

This is what I have been trying

```
//@version=5
indicator("Average Closing Price", shorttitle="ACP", overlay=true)

var label mPrice = na
var line mLine = na
var float totalClose = na
var int count = na

// Initialize totalClose and count only once
if (na(totalClose))
totalClose := close
count := 1

// Update totalClose and count in each bar
else
totalClose := totalClose + close
count := count + 1

// Draw labels and lines for each day
for i = 10 to 50 by 5
if (bar_index >= i)
    mPrice := label.new(x=bar_index + i, y=low - syminfo.mintick,      text="Day " + str.tostring(i), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.rgb(190, 190, 190), style=label.style_none, size=size.small)
    mLine := line.new(bar_index, totalClose / count, bar_index + i, totalClose / count, width=1, color=color.rgb(55, 0, 255), style=line.style_dashed, extend=extend.right)

// Draw the average line after Day 50
if (bar_index >= 50)
var float avgClose = totalClose / count
line.new(bar_index, avgClose, bar_index + 50, avgClose, width=2, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=line.style_solid)
label.new(x=bar_index + 50, y=avgClose, text="Avg Close", xloc=xloc.bar_index, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as a sample from 0 to 25 by 5:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Average Closing Price", shorttitle="ACP", overlay=true)

line_x1 = bar_index
line_x2 = bar_index + 20
line_y1 = 0.0
line_y2 = 0.0

var line avg_line  = line.new(line_x1, line_y1, line_x2, line_y1, xloc.bar_index, extend.none, color.rgb(245, 222, 48),width = 4,style = line.style_dotted )

var float avg_signal = na

avg_signal := (close + close[5] + close[10] + close[15] + close[20] + close[25])/6

if barstate.isrealtime or barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(avg_line , line_x1, avg_signal)
    line.set_xy2(avg_line , line_x2, avg_signal)
    for i = 0 to 25 by 5
        label.new(x=bar_index - i, y=low, text=str.tostring(i), xloc=xloc.bar_index, color=color.rgb(255, 241, 82), style=label.style_label_up, size=size.normal)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. It kind of helped me, but I don't think I explained well.
If I have conditions met on a certain bar, lets say Nov 1 the conditions are met I call that Day 0, and I want to add the close of Nov 8 (the 5th bar) and average their closing prices. Then Nov 15th would be the 10th bar and I want to add that to the average closing price.
The horizontal line is fixed on the x axis at Nov 1, while the yaxis moves to the new price.